# Uploaded files not showing in localhost using android

Tags: php, android, linux

I have an app that is supposed to upload a file in the server. i can select the file and upload it fine. i know it is successful because the HTTP Reponse is OK: 200. now the problem is the file and folder that is supposed to be created is nowhere to be found. i already gave the root folder read and write permissions and i am using linux. if it helps, here is the php file:

```
<?php

$file_path = "uploaded/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

?>

Comment: Do you get any error ? In which block it goes , if or else block ?

Comment: that's the thing. no errors whatsoever. the on the android monitor says http response ok 200